# Firebase Update If Exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an update function within firestore using the .update() method.

Here is the example of the function i'm running:

```
db.collection('Users').doc(offeruserid).update({
  overrideTag: process.env.A_ULTRA_SECRET_KEY,
  userExperience: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(Number(offerrate))
})
```

Now what I actually want to happen, is it look in the document and see if the field "overrideTag" is there. If it IS NOT there, it WILL NOT update it and just forget about it.

Also, I wish to do this without first getting the data, seeing if it exists, then creating a update function separately - I know it can be done that way.

Is this something that we can do within firebase?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this without first reading the document.  Usually people do check-and-set operations like this in a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), but you should be aware that transactions do read the document first before writing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in security rules, by checking for the presence of your super-secret value in the `overrideTag` field.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{user} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.overrideTag == "YOUR_SUPER_SECRET_VALUE";
    }
  }
}
```

You could also store all super-secret values somewhere in the database, and then check for their existence with an `exists` call.

```
if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/secrets/$(request.resource.data.overrideTag))
```

The latter will be a charged (so possibly paid) read operation, but you won't need to read the data in your application code.

Comment: This is what I do right now, however because I'm running it in the update command it is then storing this field in the data. I don't want it to store the field aswell

Comment: The only ways to pass data into the rules: 1) in the path of the document (i.e. the document ID), 2) in the data of the document (as you're doing now), 3) in the auth token (i.e. as custom claims).

Comment: Do they not need to be logged in to pass a auth token?

Comment: Yes, so #3 only works if you're using Firebase Authentication.